# Select specific field from documents in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I have three Schemas with this field's

```
var interactionSchema = new Schema({
    pollee: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Pollee' },
    answers: { type: [ObjectId], ref: 'Answer', autopopulate: true },
    status: type: String
});

var PolleeSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    gender: String,
    user: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true }, 
    interactions: { type: [ObjectId], ref: 'Interaction', autopopulate: true }
});

var userSchema = new Schema({
    email: String,
    pollee: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Pollee', autopopulate: true }
});
```

I need to realize a query in Pollee and pupulate fields from user and interactions, but from interactions I only need the status field, I dont need answers and other ObjectID arrays that contain the Interactions colection.

I made this Query

```
Pollee.find(req.body.filters)
        .select('id age birthday country device_register gender municipality state parish user interactions.status')
        .populate('user','email createdAt')
        .exec(function(err,pollees){
           //Other
        }
       //....
```

This return interactions array but status field is not returned. If I write only interactions on the select, return interactions with all fields from interactions.

I try this

```
Pollee.find(req.body.filters)
        .select('id age birthday country device_register gender municipality state parish user')
        .populate('user','email createdAt')
        .populate('interactions', 'status')
        .exec(function(err,pollees){
           //Other
        }
       //....
```

This return nothing from interactions

I need only Status field from interactions.

The problem here is the interactions field from Pollee Schema, this field its a Array of ObjectsId, and this field its autopopulated from Schema. I want to select only the status field from interactions

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose: deep population (populate a populated field)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867628/mongoose-deep-population-populate-a-populated-field)

Comment: @TrietDang This solution doenst work for me. The problem here is the interactions field from Pollee Schema, this field its a Array of ObjectsId, and this field its autopopulated from Schema. I want to select only the status field from interactions

Comment: Sorry, you didn't state that you use mongoose-autopopulate plugin. So I overlooked your schema.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using [mongoose-autopopulate](https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongoose-autopopulate).

It is stated in their document that you can do like [this](https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongoose-autopopulate#it-can-specify-an-options-argument):

```
var PolleeSchema = new Schema({
  //...
  interactions: { type: [ObjectId], ref: 'Interaction', autopopulate: { select: 'status' } }
});
```

Comment: I can do this in the query? I want in the query select only the specific fields from interactions Schema.

Comment: Your solution its fine but afects other controllers or functions. I want select fields from interactions only in the query not in the Schema

Comment: So, I recommend stop using auto population. Because that always populates the document and you cannot use with "original" population. If you want to population it in the query, your best bet is populate it your self.