# Is that possible to populate the inner child row of child row with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mongoose

I have two tables as **permissions** and **roles**.
Roles have permission as id reference. When I am populating roles I am getting permissions for names.

So, now I am creating a **user** with the reference id of Role. When I am populating the data of users I am getting the role with permissions id only. I want to show the permissions name also when I am populating the data of the user with the role.

**Role Schema**

```
const roleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    permissionsId: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Permission" }]
});
```

**Role output**

```
{
    "roles": [
        {
            "_id": "629bc223d571677d5e898d50",
            "name": "Admin",
            "permissionsId": [
                {
                    "name": "categoryList"
                },
                {
                    "name": "someup"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "message": "Success"
}
```

**user schema**

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    img: String,
    username: String,
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    mobile: String,
    address: String,
    role: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Role" },
    status: { type: String, enum: ['active', 'inactive'] },
    verified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    updatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    createAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

**User output**

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "_id": "629f273d84902d0201aec30e",
            "name": "Soumik",
            "img": "https://i.ibb.co/0QTSPMj/p-4.jpg",
            "username": "soumik9",
            "email": "soumik@gmail.com",
            "password": "$2b$10$V9VxSq5bdUGAZFV/04s/7.A62gP4shEC0/rnQel9VmvrAX/lFrqv.",
            "role": {
                "_id": "629bc223d571677d5e898d50",
                "name": "Admin",
                "permissionsId": [
                    "629bb7d271d26f033ac0bce8",
                    "629bbd9b62497eee720cc78e"
                ]
            },
            "status": "active",
            "verified": false,
            "updatedAt": "2022-06-07T10:23:57.633Z",
            "createAt": "2022-06-07T10:23:57.633Z"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Success"
}
```

**Expected user output**

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "_id": "629f273d84902d0201aec30e",
            "name": "Soumik",
            "img": "https://i.ibb.co/0QTSPMj/p-4.jpg",
            "username": "soumik9",
            "email": "soumik@gmail.com",
            "password": "$2b$10$V9VxSq5bdUGAZFV/04s/7.A62gP4shEC0/rnQel9VmvrAX/lFrqv.",
            "role": {
                "_id": "629bc223d571677d5e898d50",
                "name": "Admin",
                  "permissionsId": [
                {
                    "name": "categoryList"
                },
                {
                    "name": "someup"
                }
              ]
            },
            "status": "active",
            "verified": false,
            "updatedAt": "2022-06-07T10:23:57.633Z",
            "createAt": "2022-06-07T10:23:57.633Z"
        }
    ],
    "message": "Success"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the documentation [Populating across multiple levels](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate)

yes you can:

```
 UserModel
  .find({})
  .populate({
    path : 'role',
    populate : {
      path : 'permissionsId'
    }
  })
```

and please look at this question [Mongoose: deep population (populate a populated field)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867628/mongoose-deep-population-populate-a-populated-field)